# What should I do if I'm a victim of phishing attack of my iphone

Tags: phishing, iphone

I received an sms on my iphone informing me from my local delivery company that I have a parcel pending and to click on the link, which I did as the link bought me to my local delivery company home webpage which looks very legitimate (https://mysingpost.com) with all the logos imitated well. I was asked to key my mobile number into the tracking box to track the status of my parcel, which I did and immediately I received an sms code (I didn't read the whole sms until I realised the attack and the sms stated by keying this code would allow access to my apple payment) to key into the website, which I did but then I realised it was a phishing attach as there was a box with chinese word appeared. What should I do?

Comment: They already answered it for you :) https://mysingpost.com/sg/online-security-you.html

Comment: Contact Apple support if you believe your account has been compromised.